# There are always errors in console of Chrome and Visual Studio after doing the translation of web

Tags: javascript

When I debug and run my code of html(with Css qnd JavaScript) , there is a web page which has all information I want, but when I do translation in the web page, there are also the errors as those:'

Image (async)

po @ VM317:181

_.k.Ci @ VM317:381

_.k.nf @ VM317:369

_.k.Lf @ VM317:372

Rw.M @ VM317:332

Pw.s @ VM317:329

setTimeout (async)

Qw @ VM317:328

Pw.add @ VM317:328

Rw.B @ VM317:331

b @ VM317:352

px.s @ VM317:341

(anonymous) @ m=el_conf:499

eval @ VM317:346

bn @ VM317:87

next @ VM317:88

b @ VM317:88

Promise.then (async)

f @ VM317:88

eval @ VM317:88

en @ VM317:88

_.fn @ VM317:88

Vx @ VM317:346

eval @ VM317:352

qx @ VM317:341

dy.translate @ VM317:352

_.k.ei @ VM317:365

Rw.M @ VM317:332

Pw.s @ VM317:329

setTimeout (async)

Qw @ VM317:328

Pw.add @ VM317:328

Rw.B @ VM317:331

dy.U @ VM317:350

Wx.h @ VM317:346

Show 1 more frame

Show less' in the console of Chrome web , there are also those erros in the console of Visual studio:'

Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'gzip')

```
at ep.oh (<eval>/VM46947592:166:470)

at rm.flush (<eval>/VM46947592:69:71)

at eval (<eval>/VM46947592:65:445)

at Xd (//_/translate_http/_/js/k=translate_http.tr.zh_CN.so1g-IS1zUQ.O/am=AAM/d=1/rs=AN8SPfp9QE3VMkOyoC1JZMeG7Kwt9sdp6Q/m=el_conf:524:469)

at _.k.dispatchEvent (//_/translate_http/_/js/k=translate_http.tr.zh_CN.so1g-IS1zUQ.O/am=AAM/d=1/rs=AN8SPfp9QE3VMkOyoC1JZMeG7Kwt9sdp6Q/m=el_conf:523:373)

at Xl.tick (<eval>/VM46947592:64:214)

at eval (<eval>/VM46947592:63:349)

--- setTimeout ---

at Xl.start (<eval>/VM46947592:63:325)

at rm.log (<eval>/VM46947592:67:380)

at _.tm (<eval>/VM46947592:66:289)

at Tr.log (<eval>/VM46947592:166:663)

at js (<eval>/VM46947592:176:80)

at xy (<eval>/VM46947592:376:249)

at Zy (<eval>/VM46947592:441:262)

at onTranslateElementLoad (//_/translate_http/_/js/k=translate_http.tr.zh_CN.so1g-IS1zUQ.O/am=AAM/d=1/rs=AN8SPfp9QE3VMkOyoC1JZMeG7Kwt9sdp6Q/m=el_conf:362:32)

at eval (<eval>/VM46947592:443:356)

at eval (<eval>/VM46947592:443:502)

at eval (<eval>/VM46947592:446:4)

at xhr.onreadystatechange (//_/translate_http/_/js/k=translate_http.tr.zh_CN.so1g-IS1zUQ.O/am=AAM/d=1/rs=AN8SPfp9QE3VMkOyoC1JZMeG7Kwt9sdp6Q/m=el_conf:430:41)

--- XMLHttpRequest.send ---

at onLoadJavascript (//_/translate_http/_/js/k=translate_http.tr.zh_CN.so1g-IS1zUQ.O/am=AAM/d=1/rs=AN8SPfp9QE3VMkOyoC1JZMeG7Kwt9sdp6Q/m=el_conf:432:11)

at <anonymous> (//_/translate_http/_/js/k=translate_http.tr.zh_CN.so1g-IS1zUQ.O/am=AAM/d=1/rs=AN8SPfp9QE3VMkOyoC1JZMeG7Kwt9sdp6Q/m=el_conf:645:893)

at <anonymous> (//_/translate_http/_/js/k=translate_http.tr.zh_CN.so1g-IS1zUQ.O/am=AAM/d=1/rs=AN8SPfp9QE3VMkOyoC1JZMeG7Kwt9sdp6Q/m=el_conf:646:11)

at <anonymous> (//_/translate_http/_/js/k=translate_http.tr.zh_CN.so1g-IS1zUQ.O/am=AAM/d=1/rs=AN8SPfp9QE3VMkOyoC1JZMeG7Kwt9sdp6Q/m=el_conf:647:9)' . I didn't write the code of translation neither use translate API in my code. Could someone help me see what's the problem and how to solve it? All of information is correct just the errors of translation. Thanks you!
```

I reviewed my codes and I think the code is correct.I hope solve the errors, there are no errors in the console of Chrome and Visual Studio after translation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is causing this other than a conflict with other libraries and what google translate uses, but we had the same issue that just started occurring over the weekend. It was impacting our implementation with arcgis. We resolved it by adding the defer attribute to the arcgis script tag. You may be able to resolve it by adding defer to the areas of your app that may be impacting google translate to help it fully load prior to the other scripts.

```
    <script defer src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.28/"></script>
```

Comment: We are encountering the same error. Suddenly just last Friday the Google Translate started interfering with other libraries, most notably require.js.

Comment: Chromium bugreport: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1513164